# Bitwise (&) comparison in monophonic synth

Tags: c, xcode, loops, binary, midi

```
int main ()
{
    int note, velocity;
    int playingNote = -1;
    float frequency;
    printf("play the Axiom\n");

    int val = aserveGetSequenceRow(0);
    int maskedval = val & 8192;

    while(true)
    {
        note = aserveGetNote();
        velocity = aserveGetVelocity();
        if(velocity > 0)
        {
            if(maskedval == 8192)
            {
                frequency = 440 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
                aserveOscillator(0, frequency, 1.0, 0);
                playingNote = note;
            }
        }
        else if(note == playingNote)
        {
            aserveOscillator(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want this basic mono synth's first oscillator to turn on once the key on the midi controller is pressed (velocity >0) and providing aserveGetSequenceRow(0) value becomes 8192 which the user will do by turning the third switch in a 16 bit binary representation (0010000000000000)

It doesn't work! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're only getting val and maskedVal once, outside the loop - their values aren't going to change inside the loop.